# Extracting a subset of rows based on ID

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have 3 columns that look like this in Excel (taking excerpts from them to show what I mean):

```
#FID    ID      result
1004321 1004321 0
1006573 1006573 1
.
.
.
1079013 1079013 0
1081778 1079734 1
1082015 1081778 0
1087533 1082015 1
.
.
.
```

`#FID` is a subset of `ID`. However, `result` corresponds to all of `ID` which extends beyond the bounds of `#FID`. What I need to see is the results that correspond to all of `#FID`, i.e. I need to extract the rows from `ID` and `result` that correspond to the subset of ID's formed in `#FID`. Is there an easy way to do this in Excel or in some other way?

## Clarification

`#FID` is simply a subset of `ID`, i.e. all of the identifiers contained in `#FID` are also contained in `ID` - however, ID contains more identifiers than I actually need. The only ones of interest are the ones in `#FID`. However, the way I have my result column is that it corresponds to `ID`, meaning it contains results for identifiers that I don't want. I need to have all of the result's for the subset of identifiers contained in `#FID`.

## Mock up of expected result

```
#FID    result
1004321 0
1006573 1
.
.
.
1079013 0
1081778 0
1082015 1
```

**Explanation of results of mock up:** The desired result is to have all of the results that correspond to each number that exists in column `#FID`, where `#FID` is a subset of the larger column `ID` (i.e. `ID` contains all of the numbers in `#FID` and more). As it currently stands, I have the `result`'s that correspond to the column `ID` and what I need is the `result`'s that correspond to `#FID`.

**Pastebin of actual data (not large):** https://pastebin.com/KvzwvvGn

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please mock up the expected result and explain the logic that leads to the result. Right now, the relationship between the three columns is nebulous at best. As a new user read this carefully: edit your question to add the clarification, then post a comment to alert the people following the post. Do not add clarification in comments.

Comment: @teylyn I added the clarification in the post as well as a mock up of the expected result. I hope this helps to clarify what I'm asking.

Comment: @teylyn I've now also added a pastebin link to the data. It's small and reasonable to see.

Comment: How would you tell Excel which rows to include? What makes an FID a subset? Why does this row not qualify `1081778 1079734 1`, but this one does `1087533 1082015 1`?

Comment: @teylyn `#FID` is a subset of `ID` because everything contained in `#FID` is also in `ID`. However, `ID` contains **more** identifiers and corresponding `result`'s than I actually want. I need all of the results that correspond to the identifiers listed in the column `#FID` only, and I need to exclude the identifiers and results in `ID` that are not in `#FID`.  

For example, 1079734 is the first identifier in ID that is not also in #FID. I don't want the results or the number for this identifier because it's not also in #FID. However, 1082015 is in #FID so I need its result.

Comment: OK, I see the data. Now the rules. Return all rows where .... what?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108685/discussion-between-teylyn-and-psa).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Since you have not specified that, which version of Excel you working with, therefore I would like to suggest a method works with every version.*

[image]

- Formula in cell `D86`:

  ```
  =IFERROR(IF(AND(ISNUMBER(A86),A86>0),VLOOKUP(A86,B$86:C$96,2,FALSE),""),"")
  ```

**N.B.**

*As an alternative, you may use this simple version of `Index & Match`, not tests FID data, since are number as well greater than zero also.*

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$86:$C$96, MATCH(A86,$B$86:$B$96,0)), "")
```

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

Comment: This method worked in one line and it was what I needed, which is why I approved this as the accepted answer. However, teylyn's answer may also work. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help you @psa ,, keep asking ☺

Answer (score 0):

After some discussion in chat, I think the logic is as follows:

- Filter the list and return only rows with a value in the #FID column
- for each value in the filtered table, find the #FID number in the ID column and return the value from the result column of the found ID.

For ease of reference, I turned the source data into an Excel Table with Ctrl+T.

[image]

The solution uses two formulas. In cell E2 the Filter formula returns all rows with a value in the #FID column:

```
=FILTER(Table2['#FID],Table2['#FID]>0)
```

In cell F2, an Xlookup looks up the FID number in the ID column and returns the value from the result column.

```
=XLOOKUP(E2#,Table2[ID],Table2[result])
```

With Office 365, the formulas will automatically spill down as far as required and do not need to be copied down.

If you don't want to use a table, you can use range references that start in row 2, like

```
=FILTER(A2:A100,A2:A100>0)
=XLOOKUP(E2#,B2:B100,C2:C100)
```

The benefit with an Excel table is that it will automatically resize the reference if data is added or removed.

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: If that solved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]